# ClassNotFoundException when implementing interface inline

Tags: java, osgi, pom.xml, apache-karaf

I'm trying to implement an interface inline, like so:

```
client.getSubscriptionManager().addSubscriptionListener(new SubscriptionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSubscriptionTransferFailed(UaSubscription subscription, StatusCode statusCode) {

    }
});
```

But when I deploy this into an OSGi container, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.api.subscriptions.UaSubscriptionManager$SubscriptionListener not found by mybeans
```

### Details

I have a project with some beans inside of it, which are used in Apache Camel.
My beans and all neccessary dependencies get packaged into a KAR file, which I deploy into Apache Karaf. My project consists of two modules, one for the beans and one for the feature.xml, which handles my dependencies.

This is my feature.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="beans" xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0">
    <feature name='beans_feature' version='1.0'>
        <feature prerequisite="true" dependency="false">wrap</feature>
        <!-- MILO -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.milo/sdk-core/0.2.5</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.milo/sdk-client/0.2.5</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.milo/sdk-server/0.2.5</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.milo/bsd-parser-core/0.2.5</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.milo/stack-core/0.2.5</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.milo/stack-client/0.2.5</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.milo/stack-server/0.2.5</bundle>

        <!-- GOOGLE -->
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:com.google.guava/guava/19.0</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.1</bundle>

        <!-- NETTY -->
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:io.netty/netty-codec/4.0.56.Final</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:io.netty/netty-transport/4.0.56.Final</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:io.netty/netty-handler/4.0.56.Final</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:io.netty/netty-buffer/4.0.56.Final</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:io.netty/netty-common/4.0.56.Final</bundle>

        <!-- APACHE -->
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4</bundle>

        <!-- OTHER -->
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:com.codepoetics/protonpack/1.8</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-core/3.1.2</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.10.1</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.jooq/jool/0.9.10</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.json/json/20160810</bundle>

        <!-- THE ACTUAL BEANS-->
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.tcon/beans/1.0</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

### What I've tried

The only thing that makes this kind of work is if I implement the SubscriptionListener like this:

```
private final class SubscriptionListenerImpl implements SubscriptionListener {
    @Override
    public void onSubscriptionTransferFailed(final UaSubscription subscription, final StatusCode statusCode) {
        logger.info("Transfer failed {} : {}", subscription.getSubscriptionId(), statusCode);

        // we simply tear it down and build it up again
        //handleConnectionFailue(new RuntimeException("Subscription failed to reconnect"));
    }
}
```

And do this:

```
client.getSubscriptionManager().addSubscriptionListener(new SubscriptionListenerImpl());
```

But I want to implement this interface inline in order to have access to my class' fields. How can I do that?

### EDIT with details requested in comments

First, the stack trace:

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to instantiate components
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:721) ~[54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:413) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:278) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:299) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:268) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:264) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:254) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422) [54:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1179) [?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:730) [?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:485) [?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4579) [?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2174) [?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998) [?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1260) [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1233) [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1221) [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:515) [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:365) [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:316) [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/milo/opcua/sdk/client/api/subscriptions/UaSubscriptionManager$SubscriptionListener
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:1651) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.generics.TypeInference.findConstructors(TypeInference.java:180) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.generics.TypeInference.findMatchingConstructors(TypeInference.java:124) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.findMatchingConstructors(BeanRecipe.java:373) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromType(BeanRecipe.java:346) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:283) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:685) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:666) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:81) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:90) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:360) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:190) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:717) ~[?:?]
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.api.subscriptions.UaSubscriptionManager$SubscriptionListener not found by wrap_file__opt_apache-karaf-4.2.4_data_kar_features-1.0_com_tcon_beans_1.0_beans-1.0.jar [256]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1639) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:1651) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.generics.TypeInference.findConstructors(TypeInference.java:180) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.generics.TypeInference.findMatchingConstructors(TypeInference.java:124) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.findMatchingConstructors(BeanRecipe.java:373) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromType(BeanRecipe.java:346) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:283) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:685) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:666) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:81) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:90) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:360) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:190) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:717) ~[?:?]
        ... 23 more
```

Second, my plugin configs:

bean module config:

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Service>${camel.osgi.export.service}</Export-Service>
                    <Import-Package> com.google.common.*;version="19.0.0",
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Get all blueprints</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>C:/Users/krennd/Projects/camelbeans/scripts/setupUnitTests.py</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

feature module config:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-karaf-plugin-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <aggregateFeatures>false</aggregateFeatures>
                <addBundlesToPrimaryFeature>false</addBundlesToPrimaryFeature>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/${apache-karaf-version}/xml/features</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/${apache-karaf-version}/xml/features</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/${apache-camel-version}/xml/features</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>file:${project.build.directory}/feature/feature.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <features>
                            <feature>camelbeans</feature>
                        </features>
                        <distribution>org.apache.karaf.features:framework</distribution>
                        <javase>1.8</javase>
                        <framework>
                            <feature>framework</feature>
                        </framework>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### Further weirdness

I don't know how this is possbile, but this works:

```
    client.getSubscriptionManager().addSubscriptionListener(new SubscriptionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscriptionTransferFailed(UaSubscription subscription, StatusCode statusCode) {
            logger.info("Transfer failed {} : {}", subscription.getSubscriptionId(), statusCode);

            System.out.println("Subscription recreation failed, recreating subscriptions.");
            // try {

            //     // Get the items out of the old subscrp
            //     List<UaMonitoredItem> items = subscription.getMonitoredItems().asList();
            //     List<UaMonitoredItem> newItems = new ArrayList<>();
            //     List<MonitoredItemCreateRequest> MICR = new ArrayList<>();
            //     List<ReadValueId> rvIDs = new ArrayList<>();

            //     subscription = null;
            //     // Setup all neccessary variables for resubscription
            //     subscription = client.getSubscriptionManager().createSubscription(100.0).get();
            //     UInteger clientHandle = uint(clientHandles.getAndIncrement());
            //     MonitoringParameters parameters = new MonitoringParameters(clientHandle, 100.0, null, uint(10), true);

            //     for (UaMonitoredItem item : items) {
            //         rvIDs.add(item.getReadValueId());
            //     }

            //     for (ReadValueId ID : rvIDs) {
            //         MICR.add(new MonitoredItemCreateRequest(ID, MonitoringMode.Reporting, parameters));
            //     }

            //     try {
            //         newItems = subscription.createMonitoredItems(TimestampsToReturn.Both, MICR, onItemCreated).get();
            //     } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            //         e.printStackTrace();
            //     }

            //     for (UaMonitoredItem item : newItems) {
            //         if (item.getStatusCode().isGood()) {
            //             System.out.println("Item recreated for NodeId: " + item.getReadValueId().getNodeId());
            //         } else {
            //             System.out.println("Failed to recreate item for NodeId: " + item.getReadValueId().getNodeId() + item.getStatusCode());
            //         }
            //     }
            // } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1) {
            //     e1.printStackTrace();
            // }
        }
    });
```

But this doesn't:

```
    client.getSubscriptionManager().addSubscriptionListener(new SubscriptionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscriptionTransferFailed(UaSubscription subscription, StatusCode statusCode) {
            logger.info("Transfer failed {} : {}", subscription.getSubscriptionId(), statusCode);

            System.out.println("Subscription recreation failed, recreating subscriptions.");
            try {

                // Get the items out of the old subscrp
                List<UaMonitoredItem> items = subscription.getMonitoredItems().asList();
                List<UaMonitoredItem> newItems = new ArrayList<>();
                List<MonitoredItemCreateRequest> MICR = new ArrayList<>();
                List<ReadValueId> rvIDs = new ArrayList<>();

                subscription = null;
                // Setup all neccessary variables for resubscription
                subscription = client.getSubscriptionManager().createSubscription(100.0).get();
                UInteger clientHandle = uint(clientHandles.getAndIncrement());
                MonitoringParameters parameters = new MonitoringParameters(clientHandle, 100.0, null, uint(10), true);

                for (UaMonitoredItem item : items) {
                    rvIDs.add(item.getReadValueId());
                }

                for (ReadValueId ID : rvIDs) {
                    MICR.add(new MonitoredItemCreateRequest(ID, MonitoringMode.Reporting, parameters));
                }

                try {
                    newItems = subscription.createMonitoredItems(TimestampsToReturn.Both, MICR, onItemCreated).get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (UaMonitoredItem item : newItems) {
                    if (item.getStatusCode().isGood()) {
                        System.out.println("Item recreated for NodeId: " + item.getReadValueId().getNodeId());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Failed to recreate item for NodeId: " + item.getReadValueId().getNodeId() + item.getStatusCode());
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Normally there is no problem in OSGi with inline interfaces. I suppose that some of the code you use does some strange class loading. Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: This looks like an issue with dependency management. Is it excluding the anonymous implementation in the OSGI bundle?

Comment: Show your plugin configuration from your POM. If the plugin used to generate the OSGi manifest is too old, they have issues tracking Java8+ features.

Comment: I can't provide the stacktrace atm because after resuming my work this morning, it magically fixed itself. I changed nothing. This is scary for me because im my mind, it can fail anytime now.

Comment: Disregard my earlier comment. I can reproduce it now, again. I will update my question with more details.

Comment: Can you edit the post with the generated bundle manifest?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed update. I upgraded to Milo 0.3.3 and I have not gotten the error since.